Spring Framework Build Error: Cannot Find Java Toolchain
I'm trying to build the Spring Framework from source, but I'm running into an issue regarding Java toolchains when building it from IntelliJ. Here's the error message I'm getting:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':integration-tests'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':integration-tests:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
   > Cannot find a Java installation on your machine matching this tasks requirements: {languageVersion=17, vendor=BellSoft Liberica, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
      > No matching toolchain could be found in the locally installed toolchains or the configured toolchain download repositories. Some toolchain resolvers had provisioning failures: foojay (Unable to download toolchain matching the requirements ({languageVersion=17, vendor=BellSoft Liberica, implementation=vendor-specific})

I've installed Java 17 and set the variable JAVA_HOME to point to the installation.
I’m feeling quite lost on what I need to do with Gradle's toolchain configuration and the documentation isn't making things clearer for me.
I would really appreciate any guidance you can provide.
I am using Java 17.0.11 which I downloaded it from the oracle website.

The toolchain contains vendor=BellSoft Liberica so you probably need that JDK specifically.

Please refer to this gradle issue
The resolution is given here
configure the foojay resolver plugin
  plugins {
      id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver") version "0.4.0"
  }

  toolchainManagement {
      jvm {
          javaRepositories {
              repository("foojay") {
                  resolverClass.set(org.gradle.toolchains.foojay.FoojayToolchainResolver::class.java)
              }
          }
      }
  }

